# How to create many copies of a single file with different names using command prompt?

Tags: file, cmd, copy, windows-10

I need to create new copies of a single .html file. The file's name is `065.html`.
I copied the file into `066.html` using the following command:

```
C:\>copy 065.html 066.html
```

But I need more. I need to copy up to `090.html`

How can I do this? A loop should do this but I don't know the syntax.

I have tried to use the command as shown [here](https://serverfault.com/a/165312/206679),

```
for /L %%i IN (66,1,90) do copy 065.html 0%%i.html
```

but I get an error message that says

> %%i was unexpected at this time

Comment: If you are doing this interactively at the cmd shell prompt, only one (1) percent sign should be used. Use two (2) percent signs when putting the code into a .bat or .cmd script file.

Comment: @Liturgist Thanks. I was late too notice that.

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted one preceding `%` signs. It works now.

```
for /L %i IN (66,1,90) do copy 065.html 0%i.html
```